# Ask for only either Face ID or Fingerprint Id in Android app

Tags: android, fingerprint, android-biometric-prompt, face-id, android-biometric

I want an implementation such that if both Face ID and fingerprint ID is enabled in user's device - my app will ask for authentication with Face ID, if only Face ID is enabled in user's device - my app will ask for authentication with Face ID, and if only fingerprint ID is enabled in user's device - my app will ask for fingerprint ID.

Right now, my app authenticates with both fingerprint ID and Face ID, if both are enabled in user's device.

I am using the following code snippets:

```
//BELOW CODE IS SUPPOSED TO CHECK IF AUTHENTICATION WITH FINGERPRINT IS POSSIBLE
  var canAuthenticateFingerprint = biometricManager.canAuthenticate(BiometricManager.Authenticators.BIOMETRIC_STRONG)

//BELOW CODE IS SUPPOSED TO CHECK IF AUTHENTICATION WITH Face ID IS POSSIBLE
       var canAuthenticateFaceAuth = biometricManager.canAuthenticate(BiometricManager.Authenticators.BIOMETRIC_WEAK)

 //BELOW CODE STORES IN PREFERENCES THE FLAG FOR SUPPORTED AUTHENTICATION METHODS

                if (canAuthenticateFingerprint == BIOMETRIC_SUCCESS
                    && canAuthenticateFaceAuth == BIOMETRIC_SUCCESS)
                {
                    prefsUseCase.setFaceSecurityEnabled(true)
                    prefsUseCase.setFingerprintSecurityEnabled(true)
                }
    
                else if (canAuthenticateFaceAuth == BIOMETRIC_SUCCESS
                    && canAuthenticateFingerprint != BIOMETRIC_SUCCESS)
                {
                    prefsUseCase.setFaceSecurityEnabled(true)
                    prefsUseCase.setFingerprintSecurityEnabled(false)
                }
                else if (canAuthenticateFingerprint == BIOMETRIC_SUCCESS
                    && canAuthenticateFaceAuth != BIOMETRIC_SUCCESS){
                    prefsUseCase.setFaceSecurityEnabled(false)
                    prefsUseCase.setFingerprintSecurityEnabled(true)
                }


//BELOW CHECKS IF Face ID OR FINGERPRINT AUTHENTICATION IS SUPPORTED OR NOT AND
//TAKES APPROPRIATE ACTION

var canAuthenticate = biometricManager.
            canAuthenticate(BiometricManager.Authenticators.BIOMETRIC_WEAK
                    or BiometricManager.Authenticators.BIOMETRIC_STRONG)
                when (canAuthenticate) {
                    BiometricManager.BIOMETRIC_SUCCESS -> {
                        confirmBiometrics()
                    }

                    else -> sendNavigateToHomePageEvent()

                }
} 

//BELOW METHOD IS SUPPOSED TO USE AUTHENTICATION WITH EITHER FACE ID OR FINGERPRINT //ID
 
 private fun getPromptInfo(): BiometricPrompt.PromptInfo {

        if ((prefsUseCase.isFaceSecurityEnabled() &&
            prefsUseCase.isFingerprintSecurityEnabled())
            || prefsUseCase.isFaceSecurityEnabled()) {
            promptInfo = BiometricPrompt.PromptInfo.Builder()
                .setTitle("Biometric login")
                .setSubtitle("Log in using your biometric credential")
                .setNegativeButtonText("Use passcode")
                .setAllowedAuthenticators(BIOMETRIC_WEAK)
                .build()
        }

        else if ((prefsUseCase.isFingerprintSecurityEnabled() &&
                    !prefsUseCase.isFaceSecurityEnabled())){
            promptInfo = BiometricPrompt.PromptInfo.Builder()
                .setTitle("Biometric login")
                .setSubtitle("Log in using your biometric credential")
                .setNegativeButtonText("Use passcode")
                .setAllowedAuthenticators(BIOMETRIC_STRONG)
                .build()
        }

    return promptInfo
}
```

How do I make it such that only one authentication method according to my requirement, as mentioned in beginning of this post, is used instead of both?